# JSP Database setDate

Tags: sql, jsp

```
// Create the prepared statement and use it to
// INSERT the student attributes INTO the Student table.
PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(
"INSERT INTO Review VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");

pstmt.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("section_id")));
pstmt.setString(2, request.getParameter("quarter"));                   
pstmt.setInt(3, Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("year")));
pstmt.setDate(4, ????)
```

Can anyone tell me how do i deal with the type Date??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to parse a String into `java.util.Date` object.

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
Date date = format.parse(request.getParameter("date"));
```

Then you can convert `java.util.Date` to `java.sql.Date` in order to use in `PreparedStatement`:

```
java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(date.getTime());
PreparedStatement pst = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
pst.setDate(4, sqlDate);
```

Comment: Thx for the help! but Eclipse says SimpleDateFormat cannot be used as a type??